# Publish and Generating Room Elements For a Revit Model (C4R)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

I am working on Data visualization forge API to add a sprite sensor to some  `rooms (architecture model) / spaces (Mep model)`. in general, I am using [Data Management API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/PublishModel/) to publish but I am wondering if it is a way to include rooms element/spaces element with the same API...

because at the [documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/quickstart/generating_room_elements/) it seems possible only to non C4R models

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Revit models published to BIM360 Docs will get master views translated by default. So, you don't need to follow the instruction to request mater viewer translation. Just remember to load master viewers in Forge Viewer.

In the response of [GET :urn/manifest](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/), there is a new attribute called `isMasterView` to help identify if the view is an Revit master view.

```json
{
    "isMasterView": true,
    "phaseNames": "Working Drawings",
    "role": "3d",
    "hasThumbnail": "true",
    "children": [
        {
            "guid": "c884ae1b-61e7-4f9d-0001-719e20b22d0b-0010beed",
            "type": "view",
            "role": "3d",
            "name": "Working Drawings",
            "status": "success",
            "progress": "complete",
            "camera": [
                124.7886734008789,
                -152.5997772216797,
                133.87307739257812,
                7.490562438964844,
                -35.301666259765625,
                16.574966430664062,
                -0.40824830532073975,
                0.40824830532073975,
                0.8164966106414795,
                1.285019040107727,
                0,
                1,
                1
            ]
        },
//...
        {
            "role": "graphics",
            "mime": "application/autodesk-svf2",
            "guid": "18474dc1-df69-767f-47ee-33e5eac5599d",
            "type": "resource"
        }
    ],
    "name": "Working Drawings",
    "guid": "e4baebbb-4ad6-8223-7f6a-cad4f0bb353a",
    "progress": "complete",
    "type": "geometry",
    "viewableID": "c884ae1b-61e7-4f9d-0001-719e20b22d0b-0010beed",
    "status": "success"
},
```

In Forge Viewer, we can do something like the below to load master views.

```js
const root = viewerDocument.getRoot();
const viewables = root.search({'type':'geometry', 'role': '3d'});

console.log('Viewables:', viewables);

const phaseViews = viewables.filter(v => v.data.name === v.data.phaseNames && v.getViewableRootPath().includes('08f99ae5-b8be-4f8d-881b-128675723c10'));

console.log('Master Views:', phaseViews);

const defaultModel = phaseViews[0];

viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, defaultModel);
```